# Send message to telegram channel with telethon and get mobile notification

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want to use telethon to send messages to my own private channel, and receive mobile push notifications when the python script posts a message. With the below code I'm able to send the messages, but I do not receive any mobile push notifications. I've turned on all notification settings in the mobile app. I have been googling around for 'telethon push notifications', without any luck.

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = 'api_id'
api_hash = 'api_hash'
username = 'username'
channel_invite_link = 'channel invite link'


async def func():
    entity = await client.get_entity(channel_invite_link)
    await client.send_message(entity=entity, message="Hi")


with TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(func())
```

Comment: You don't receive push notifications because you are the one who sent the message. Sent it either with another account or with a bot. If you are already doing this and it's not working probably you can't get notifications from your own channel. I never tried this myself.

Comment: Assuming it's your channel, you can create a bot (via [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather)), add it as admin to your channel, and use the bot to send the message. This way you should get a notification, because like nitan said, you don't if you're the one sending the message.

Comment: @Lonami: I've followed your tips, and created a bot with BotFather which I use to send messages. I now receive push notifications as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `silent` argument, i.e.:

```py
await client.send_message(entity=entity, message="Hi", silent=False)
```